# Best way to get maximum data from Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an Android app which uses Facebook Graph API. Currently I am researching status posts(news feed and wall). However I have noticed that Graph API 'me/feed' or 'me/home' does not provide all the posts.

For one of test accounts which shows 5 posts on wall from the official Facebook UI, I get only 2 posts for 'me/home'. Pagination leads to empty data.

In case of FQL also I have notice that complete data is not returned. FQL doesn't seem to have any pagination.

Am I missing something? Did you have any similar experience? If yes, what trick did you use to get all/maximum data.

Answer (score 0):

The graph API is constantly changing so this may or may not work now...

Try adding limit=0 to the Graph API query.  At one point the default was 25 if it's not set, setting it to 0 is supposed to be "unlimited".  However, this is no guarantee of getting all results.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. Tried to set limit=0 in the graph api explorer it doesn't seem to change the result. For now I am limiting the fields to required ones only and setting limit=500. It seems to give me at least 500.